# SqlLite with SqlAlchemy CreateTable result in database is locked

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

While trying to figure out why my tests fails to create sqlite schema, I tried this very simple example issued from https://pysheeet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/python-sqlalchemy.html

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String

db_uri = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
engine = create_engine(db_uri)

# Create a metadata instance
metadata = MetaData(engine)
# Declare a table
table = Table('Example',metadata,
              Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('name',String))
# Create all tables
metadata.create_all()
for _t in metadata.tables:
   print("Table: ", _t)
```

But still I get this db locked message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE "Example" (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tname VARCHAR, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Any idea of how to use create all with non 'in memory' sqlite db ?

Comment: According to the docs http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#database-locking-behavior-concurrency Sqllite is not designed for high writing concurrency. Have you created the database beforehand? check your `db_uri`  once again. Can you query the db with the command line? Have a look at here as well http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite

Comment: Well, assuming the only script executed is the code I showed you, nothing else. I wouldn't expect some writing concurrency to occur while creating the tables, right?